# How do I deal with this windows phone webclient asynchronous issue?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, asynchronous, webclient

I have a method as follows:

```
      public decimal GetExchangeRate(string fromCurrency, string toCurrency)
      {
            GoogleCurrencyService googleCurrencyService = new GoogleCurrencyService();
            return googleCurrencyService.GetRateForCurrency(fromCurrency, toCurrency);

      }
```

and another class as follows

```
public class GoogleCurrencyService
{
    public decimal GetRateForCurrency(string fromCurrency, string toCurrency)
    {

        try
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(StringDownloadCompleted);
            client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(_requestUri + fromCurrency + "=?" + toCurrency));

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            ExchangeRate = 0;
        }

        return ExchangeRate;
    }

    private void StringDownloadCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        _response = e.Result;
        ExchangeRate = ParseResponseAndGetExchangeRate();
    }

}//class GoogleCurrencyService
```

the variable ExchangeRate always come out as zero, so I believe the function call "GetRateForCurrency" returns before the async callback gets called. How do I make sure that does not happen as I need the variable ExchangeRate  to be set before being returned. Thanks. Also, I have noticed that the callback never gets called as I have a breakpoint in it and the exception as well which does not get called. So I donot know where the problem is.Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an event wait handle to block the current thread and wait for the async call...

```
public class GoogleCurrencyService
{
    private const string RequestUri = "http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=1{0}%3D%3F{1}";

    public decimal ExchangeRate { get; private set; }

    public decimal GetRateForCurrency(string fromCurrency, string toCurrency)
    {
        ExchangeRate = 0;
        // use a signaler to block this thread and wait for the async call.
        var signaler = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        try
        {
            var client = new WebClient();
            client.DownloadStringCompleted += StringDownloadCompleted;
            // pass the signaler as user token
            client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(String.Format(RequestUri, fromCurrency, toCurrency)), signaler);

            // wait for signal, it will be set by StringDownloadCompleted
            signaler.WaitOne();
        }
        finally
        {
            signaler.Dispose();
        }

        return ExchangeRate;
    }

    private void StringDownloadCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ExchangeRate = ParseResponseAndGetExchangeRate(e.Result);
        }
        finally
        {
            // set signal
            ((ManualResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();
        }
    }

    private decimal ParseResponseAndGetExchangeRate(string result)
    {
        return 123;
    }
}
```

**EDIT: The same class using an async pattern**

```
public class GoogleCurrencyService
{
    private const string RequestUri = "http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=1{0}%3D%3F{1}";

    public void GetRateForCurrency(string fromCurrency, string toCurrency, Action<decimal> callback)
    {
        var client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += StringDownloadCompleted;
        // pass the callback as user token
        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(String.Format(RequestUri, fromCurrency, toCurrency)), callback);
    }

    private void StringDownloadCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // parse response to get the rate value
        var rate = ParseResponseAndGetExchangeRate(e.Result);

        // if a callback was specified, call it passing the rate.
        var callback = (Action<decimal>)e.UserState;
        if (callback != null)
            callback(rate);
    }

    private decimal ParseResponseAndGetExchangeRate(string result)
    {
        return 123;
    }
}
```

**Consuming the async class:**

```
// this is your UI form/control/whatever
public class MyUI
{
    public void OnButtonToGetRateClick()
    {
        var from = "USD"; // or read from textbox...
        var to = "EUR";

        // call the rate service
        var service = new GoogleCurrencyService();
        service.GetRateForCurrency(from, to, (rate) =>
            {
                // do stuff here to update UI.
                // like update ui.
            });
    }
}
```

Maybe you'll have to dispatch the UI changes to ui thread. I not have WP framework here to confirm that this is the case, but I think it is.

Comment: Hi devundef, same as my comment above, I cannot call the mentioned sync method DownloadString as it doesnt exist.

Comment: I have tried your solution, but now my code goes into an infinite wait sequence.

Comment: @Evra, wait a moment, I'll test here.

Comment: It worked for me. An exception could prevent the call to Set() method. I put all inside a try..finally block. The class I used to test is on my answer.

Comment: Are you calling this service from the main thread(ui) ? Because by doing this the UI will freeze until get the google service response.

Comment: Yes I believe I am calling it from amin thread ui as I hadnt done any special ui thread tweaks of any sort. If that is the case, how do I remedy the issue?

Comment: You'll have to do it asynchronous. I'm not get my hands on WP framework yet, but I think it is designed using async patterns. You'll have to get some information about that, because I can't really explain to you here. You can start by this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2010/10/28/making-asynchronous-programming-easy.aspx

Answer (score 0):

when you run an async method, you will get result in completed method that is

StringDownloadCompleted

so in your code you call async method and return immediatly ExchangeRate which will always be 0.

you have to get ExchangeRate in your completed method StringDownloadCompleted

if you want to get ExchangeRate in your GetRateForCurrency make a synchronous call

```
client.DownloadString(new Uri(_requestUri + fromCurrency + "=?" + toCurrency));
```

Comment: Hi Hassan, thanks for the reply but as far as I am concerned there is no DownloadString method in the Webclient instance or I'm I missing something. I tried calling it but it doesnt show up in intellisense..

Comment: it is surprising see this msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.webclient_methods(v=vs.80)

Comment: Hi Hassan, I have checked the link and the DownloadString method exists but Webclient class for windows phone has only async methods and so this link does not apply in this case as my program is for windows phone7.1

Comment: @HassanBoutougha - Use the Silverlight "version" when looking up WP7 APIs. The [Silverlight docs for WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient_methods%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) only lists async APIs.

Answer (score 0):

here's what you need to do.

you create an eventin the class.
in your code, you fire the async web client call. Once the call is complete, you wrap the data and set the event. I tend to define event args which can hold the data.

once you set the event the caller will get notified.

if you want an example, have a look at the source in my post here
http://invokeit.wordpress.com/2012/06/30/bing-mapcontrol-offline-tiles-solution-wpdev-wp7dev/

its an extension of bing maps sample and it contains address finder class. have a look at how it is fired and how client gets notified

Answer (score 0):

ok wait after call uri

public decimal GetRateForCurrency(string fromCurrency, string toCurrency)
    {

```
    try
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(StringDownloadCompleted);
        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(_requestUri + fromCurrency + "=?" + toCurrency));
        Thread.sleep(500000); //waiting
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        ExchangeRate = 0;
    }

    return ExchangeRate;
}
```

so set a webcontrol like label and do this

```
 private void StringDownloadCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    _response = e.Result;
    yourlabel.Text = _response ;
    ExchangeRate = ParseResponseAndGetExchangeRate();
}
```

Comment: I only intend to parse the response from the url I am calling, not show it on some label as it is a json string.

Comment: I understand, it is only to show you that you will get the correct value on StringDownloadCompleted method so instead of yourlabel.Text set your working at the same place

Comment: I appreciate the help but the exchangerate variable gets returned immediately before even StringDownloadCompleted callback gets executed. I acknowledge that if I were to set the text to an a label, I would get the correct value but that is not the case as I need to prevent the method from returning with wrong value before the async callback gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

Your only choice here to make `GetRateForCurrency` asynchronous too (which means raising its own `Completed` event).

Is the TPL were supported, you could use `Task<T>` as a nice way to wrap the asynchony down the chain, but unfortunately it's not supported by WP7.

As an alternative, and what I've done, is to use the Reactive Extensions (`Microsoft.Phone.Reactive`) and pass an `IObservable` down the chain - however, Rx is a lot to learn if you're only going ot use it for this one scenario.

Comment: How do I go about changing GetRateForCurrency to asynchronous. By any means I am no expert in the asynchronous topic also.

Comment: @Evra - Take a look at [Event-based Asynchronous Pattern Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wewwczdw.aspx), which is a rundown on the pattern in question.